# Switch case bug?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, default

So I got this very simple switch case, from a local variable I import the value into the function and it's primary function is to switch from french to english alias and return the value to my javascript...

If for some reason the ALIAS of a page doesn't figure in the cases it should go to default and trigger my jsbreak function, however in my case even if the alias is detected and it toggles the variable to the new values it will still go to Default and execute the code...

```
function langToggle(currentAlias) {
    switch(currentAlias) {
    //Switch the variable from English to French and vice versa depending on the current page's URL string when the toggle js link is clicked
        //If ENGLISH switch the variable to French
        //If ENGLISH switch the variable to French
        case "about-us": currentAlias = "a-notre-sujet"; break;
        //If FRENCH switch the variable to French
        case "a-notre-sujet": currentAlias = "about-us"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "facilities-and-security": 
            currentAlias = "installations-et-securite"; break; 
        case "installations-et-securite": 
            currentAlias = "facilities-and-security"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "offenders": 
            currentAlias = "delinquants"; break; 
        case "delinquants": 
            currentAlias = "offenders"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "you-and-csc": 
            currentAlias = "scc-et-vous"; break; 
        case "scc-et-vous": 
            currentAlias = "you-and-csc"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "connecting": 
            currentAlias = "etablir-des-liens"; break; 
        case "etablir-des-liens": 
            currentAlias = "connecting"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "resources": 
            currentAlias = "ressources"; break; 
        case "ressources": 
            currentAlias = "resources"; break;
        /*--------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "international-transfers": 
            currentAlias = "transferements-internationaux"; break; 
        case "transferements-internationaux": 
            currentAlias = "international-transfers"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "educational-resources": 
            currentAlias = "ressources-pedagogiques"; break; 
        case "ressources-pedagogiques": 
            currentAlias = "educational-resources"; break;
        /* -------------------------------------[ See the first two comments ]---------------------------------- */
        case "cfp": 
            currentAlias = "pfc"; break; 
        case "pfc": 
            currentAlias = "cfp"; break;
        default: alert("the no matching alias");
    }
    //Return the value of the updated Alias to the language toggle script
    return currentAlias;
}
```

this is the OTHER function calling the toggle script for those saying it might be bugged?

```
function jsabort(){
    throw new Error('This is not an error. This is just to abort javascript');
}   
function js_changeit(){ 
    var mainName = String(window.location);
    var dash = mainName.lastIndexOf("-");
    var slash = mainName.lastIndexOf("/");  
    var dot = mainName.lastIndexOf(".");
    var name = mainName.substring(slash+1,dot);
    var ext = mainName.substring(dot,mainName.length);
    var lang = name.substring(name.length-3,name.length);
    var urlSection = mainName.split("/");
    var currentAlias = urlSection[3];
    var currentSite = urlSection[2];
    var urlUntilEndAlias = "http://" + currentSite + "/" + currentAlias + "/";
    var mainUrlSplittedAtAlias = mainName.split(urlUntilEndAlias);
    var mainUrlSplittedAtAliasLastSlash  = mainUrlSplittedAtAlias[1];
    if (mainName === "http://internet/index-eng.shtml" || mainName === "http://internet/index-fra.shtml" ) {
        if (lang != "eng") {
            window.open("http://" + currentSite + "/" + "index" + "-eng" + ext, "_self");
        } else if (lang != "fra") {
            window.open("http://" + currentSite + "/" + "index" + "-fra" + ext, "_self");
        }
    } else {
    var lastDash = mainUrlSplittedAtAliasLastSlash.lastIndexOf("-");
    var subSectionUntilEndFilename = mainUrlSplittedAtAliasLastSlash.substring(0,lastDash);
    var UpdatedAlias = langToggle(currentAlias);
    langToggle();
        if (lang != "eng") {
            window.open("http://" + currentSite + "/" + UpdatedAlias + "/" + subSectionUntilEndFilename + "-eng" + ext, "_self");
        } else if (lang != "fra") {
        window.open("http://" + currentSite + "/" + UpdatedAlias + "/" + subSectionUntilEndFilename + "-fra" + ext, "_self");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `switch` for this? A plain object used as map would take less than half the amount of code.

Comment: This works for me. See http://jsfiddle.net/UAacc/

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jon mentioned in the comments, you should use a lookup-object to solve this problem:

```
var lookup = {
    "about-us":        "a-notre-sujet",
    "a-notre-sujet":   "about-us",
    "offenders":       "delinquants",
    // ...
};

var langToggle = lookup[ currentAlias ];

if(!langToggle) {
    alert("the no matching alias");
}
```

Comment: I've been coding javascript for about 3 days now, thanks for the tip, will be trying that.

Comment: in general, that statement is not so useful. Can you re-define that in something more accurate?

Comment: I copy pasted that code into the langDB.js function script and when I click on my toggle look in a page containing about-us as an alias in the string of the url it does not load it... see above code, I updated the post with my primary function.

Comment: @EricSP: I don't really know what you expect to happen or what should happen. Anyway, `langToggle` is supposed to return a string, you're just calling the function right-away without storing or assigning its return value anywhere. So if "doesn't work" has to do with that, its your first issue.

Comment: Basically my original Switch case script took the value of currentAlias in the primary script then it brought it in LangDB.js from there it was "loaded" into the switch and each case evaluated the value of the currentAlias variable and set it as it's opposite french value when detected and then at the very end it returned the value of currentAlias and when the primary script calls ToggleAlias() it then loads the new alias name into the final condition at the end of primary script where based on the string extension of the URL it will allocate the alternative variable value to UpdatedAlias...

Comment: At the moment when I load the code above, even if I put alert("test"); at the very top it won't trigger the lookup object...

Comment: keep in mind that the lookup table and the actual script are two seperate files...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (even though for this case the solution should not use a switch with strings but a table like it was suggested by jAndy).

So in case there isn't a syntax error or some miss placed breaks you should (could?) do something like this:

```
function langToggle(currentAlias) {
    var myKey = '' + currentAlias;
    switch(myKey) {
       case 'XPTO':
           //do xpto
           break;
       case 'YPTO':
           //do ypto
           break;
    }
}
```

In my case I was sure that I was passing strings, so this is not just to convert the argument to a string, but to create a new string object. This way worked to me. I would like to give a better explanation why it works but I don't have it :) Hope this helps anyone.

If anyone knows a better reason please share!

Comment: Update: Not entirely sure, but in my case this might be related with JavaScript's (UTF16) encoding, the step were I initialize the myKey variable might be fixing some weird character that I was sending from the server that i couldn't "see" on the text editor. The other day I was comparing code with a previous version and I detected one of those situations.